# How to refresh database data in Excel at regular intervals?

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel spreadsheet/VBA script I'm making, I need to call data from a database, and refresh the values every 5 minutes. The program starts from the push of a button, and should run continuously until the user breaks the execution. I'm currently not sure how to make Excel/VBA 'wait' 5 minutes without pausing the spreadsheet and, ideally, without being computationally inefficient.

I've tried using the "Application.Wait" and "Sleep" functions, but both of those pause the spreadsheet during the 5 minute wait.

My current solution is to use a "While" loop with "DoEvents" inside it, as shown in the code below. This makes the program just run the "While" loop for 5 minutes, and it does not pause the spreadsheet thanks to "DoEvents". However, while the spreadsheet is usable, this is computationally inefficient, since the program execution isn't technically paused, it's just running the "While" loop continuously, and some of the slower computers that may end up using my program might be significantly slowed by this.

My current solution is as follows:

```
    Sub MainProgram()
    'dimension variables, open database connection, etc.
    Do While 1 < 2 'ad infinitum
        'get database data, write to spreadsheet, etc.
        WasteTime()
    Loop
    End Sub


    Sub WasteTime()
    EndTime = Now + TimeSerial(0,5,0)
    While Now < EndTime
        DoEvents
    Wend
    End Sub
```

The problem with this, as mentioned above, is the computational inefficiency. CPU utilization is fairly high throughout the WasteTime loop. So I'm wondering, is there any way to pause the script without pausing the spreadsheet and without running the code continuously, thus burdening the CPU?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [`Application.OnTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime).

Comment: Perhaps turn on Auto Saving, and set the [interval for that](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2588-excel-change-autosave-time.html).  Then add a `Workbook.BeforeSave` event that refreshes the data?

Comment: Application.OnTime worked! Thank you BigBen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BigBen mentions in comments [Application.OnTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime) is the best option for this. It avoids the overhead you describe by scheduling a second macro to be called at a future time.

Below is an example. You can modify the wait time with the constant variable. These should be within the same Module (or change `theCalculation` macro to not be private).

```
Sub TheTimerMac()
     'enter in timevalue (hour:Minute:Second)
     Const DelayTime As String = "00:05:00" 

     Dim nextRunTime As Date
     nextRunTime = Now + TimeValue(DelayTime)

     'Schedules application to execute below macro at set time.
     Application.OnTime nextRunTime, "TheCalculation"

End Sub



Private Sub TheCalculation()
     'whatever you use for your calc here
     Application.CalculateFull

     'This will restart the timer portion.
     Call TheTimerMac

End Sub
```